# Applying Inclusion-Exclusion principle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

How to apply principle of inclusion-exclusion to this problem?

> Eight people enter an elevator at the first floor. The elevator
>   discharges passengers on each successive floor until it empties on the
>   fifth floor. How many different ways can this happen

The people are  **distinguishable**.

Comment: What have you tried? Are the persons distinguishable, or are only the numbers of persons relevant? Add this to your question (not in a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $4^8$ possibilities to do it with out any restrictions.
We want to count the bad cases, that is cases where there is a floor which no one get down in.
Here you must use inclusion-exclusion.

$A_i=$ number of ways in which no one drops in the $i$ floor.

You need to calculate the cardinality of $X$ where
$$X=A_2\cup \cup A_3 \cup A_4 \cup A_5,$$ 
and your answer is
$$4^8-|X|.$$

Comment: So we assume that atleast one person is unloaded on each floor?

Comment: @Pradeep , Yes because "discharges passengers on each successive floor".

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** There are $ \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j}{{k}\choose {j} }j^n$ ways. k are the number of distinguishable people and n is the number of floors.

The formula can be looked up under the term "*twelvefold way*" and "*Stirling number*" (second kind).

Comment: Tried the same formula. But did not get the right answer.
The correct answer is $4^8 - \binom{4}{1} 3^8 + \binom{4}{2} 2^8 - \binom{4}{3} 1^8$

Comment: @Pradeep Your answer is "correct" for **distinguishable** passengers, assuming that at least one passenger gets off at each floor. A translation error, perhaps?

Comment: @Pradeep I have made an edit.